# accessing mongodb's object from mapper (MapReduce)

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mapreduce

I have an extra question based on the one I asked before:
[calculate frequency using mongodb aggregate framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860956/calculate-frequency-using-mongodb-aggregate-framework)

so my data in MongoDB looks like this now:

```
{
    "data": {
        "interaction": {
            "created_at": "Wed, 09 Apr 2014 14:38:16 +0000"
        }
    },
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53455b59edcd5e4e3fdd4ebb"
    }
}
```

before I used to have it like:

```
[
  {
     created_at: "2014-03-31T22:30:48.000Z",
     id: 450762158586880000,
     _id: "5339ec9808eb125965f2eae1"
  }
]
```

so to access `created_at` I was using mapper like:

```
var mapper = function () {

    if ( this.created_at.getTime() > ( last_date + 10000 ) ) {
...
```

but as the structure in my database has changed, I tried to change:

```
this.created_at.getTime()
```

to:

```
this.data.interaction.created_at.getTime()
```

but unfortunately it didn't work out. Thank you for any help

Comment: So to be clear, your new interaction `created_at` seems to have an entirely different format from what it was. In fact it looks like a string. Is this how it actually represents now or are you just abstracting? For `Date` type operations to work this should still present as an `ISODate` object through the shell.

Comment: thanks again, this is how my Date looks like in db. I'm saving data straight from twitter to db. I could convert it using this: `var created_at = data.created_at; var d = new Date(created_at);`
but I'd like to do that as I read the data, not when I save it

Comment: So back to what I was saying, dates as strings are "bad". You need to make some effort to parse those strings from  the twitter feed into an actual date format before inserting into MongoDB. This is actually what is causing your problem since the built in `Date` functions from JavaScript cannot do anything with a string.

Comment: but can I read from mongodb `"Wed, 09 Apr 2014 14:38:16 +0000"`, then put it into new variable, convert and use it in mapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to make this that simple but all you want to do when importing these date strings is this:

```js
new Date("Wed, 09 Apr 2014 14:38:16 +0000")
```

Which will return a proper date type that you actually should be inserting as part of your data.